# Where are the all documents/files physically stores in Sense/Net after uploading?

Tags: sensenet

I a trying to figure out where all documents  physically stores after uploading on portal. I find out nodes table in database which show the path of documents. i want to know path of document storage and how i can change default document  storage location or give new disk path location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sense/Net everything is stored in the Content Repository, meaning the database by default. You can switch on the [FileStream feature](http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_enable_FILESTREAM_in_Sense/Net) of MS SQL Server, Sense/Net supports that, but that feature will be phased out in the future, because SQL Server uses too much storage in some environments.

There is a possibility to store binaries in a [separate blob storage](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Blob_provider). The *Enterprise* edition contains a blob provider for [MongoDb](http://wiki.sensenet.com/MongoDB_blob_provider); *Community* users may create a custom solution based on a [sample code](http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_create_an_external_blob_provider).

In the default installation these are the SQL tables that you can take a look at:

- **Nodes** (as you have found out, this is the central table).
- **Versions**: one or more versions per content (can be joined with Nodes).
- **BinaryProperties**: metadata table for binary values (can be joined to Versions).
- **Files**: real binary data in case of default behavior, connected to the BinaryProperties table above.

For details, see this article: [Sense/Net database structure](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Database_structure)

Comment: Thank you for quick replay,it clears my doubt but what is storage limit for community users;ya its depends on system/server storage size?

Comment: SenseNet does not set a storage limit; that limit is set by your database store. If you use SQL Express 2012 or 2014 your limit is 10 GB.